# how to fire an event after certain clicks on link by jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to show a popup after every 4 clicks on different links by jQuery.

I have different links which are going to their relative pages after page refresh.How can I show the popup after every 4 links click?

```
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">About</a>
<a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
<a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
<a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
```

Here is my script which i am using

```
(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $(a).click(function () {
        count += 1;
        if (count == 4) {
            // popup code
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: check i have updated my question.

Comment: you should save the counter in a place where you can again get it after page load. Use local Storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.data()` to store number of clicks for that particular link as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      if($(this).data("numberOfClicks")){
        var currentClicks = $(this).data("numberOfClicks");
        currentClicks++;
        $(this).data("numberOfClicks",currentClicks);

        if(currentClicks % 4 == 0)
          alert($(this).text()+" clicked "+currentClicks+" times...!");
        }
    else
      {
        $(this).data("numberOfClicks",1);
        }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">About</a>
<a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
<a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
<a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay for you answer but I want to fire the events after every 4 links click,(multiple of 4, like, after 4 ,after 8, after 12 and so on)

Comment: numberOfClicks holds the number of clicked happened with that particular `<a>` link

Comment: Ok Thanks,but after page refresh it is not working :(

Comment: HTTP works on request/response architecture. So current page request is entirely unaware of previously made request. Due to this only we generally go for server side session management. Its equally applicable for JavaScript/JQuery variables. Once you go to next page or refresh current page; whatever value you modified gets lost and again those variables gets set to their initial values. In your case I will suggest to go for browser based cookies to store number of clicks instead of `$.data()`

Comment: Ok..I am trying to write such script.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : you can have count data for each link and call `e.preventDefault()` if click is not the forth click.

```js
$(function(){
   $('a').click(function(e){
         var count = parseInt($(this).data('count')) || 0;
         count++;
         if(count%4!=0)
            e.preventDefault();
          
         $(this).data('count',count);
   });    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">About</a>
<a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
<a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
<a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var $count = 0;

            $('a').click(function () {

                $count += 1;

                if ($count == 4) {

                    alert(" 4 clicks on different  links");

                    //define the event  function here
                    // bind the event  with the html elements 
                }
            });



        });



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a  id="home"href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a>

</body>
</html>

enter code here
```